# Css divs side by side with oblique line

Tags: html, css

I want to create 2 floated div elements that will take up 50% of all the browser's window.
The left div will have light green background color. The right will have dark green background color.
Well, its as easy as having each div set with 50% width.

However, I need the left div to end as an oblique line.
I attach the image that explains how this div should look like.

I have followed a few resources that explain how to create elements with different geometrical shapes.
It seems mostly be about setting values for border (for example right border) and the making transparent the corresponding border top/bottom.

The difficulty Im facing is about the fact that Im using both percentage and pixels for the elements. And this doesnt give good result.

This code here:

```
 #div1 {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 display: inline-block;
 border-left: 30px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 30px solid #24890d;
 height: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 }

<div style="width: 100%;background-color: red">
<div style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#58c333;padding-top: 11px">
aa
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#58c333;" id="div1">
bb
</div>
</div>
```

Will make the second div to go the next line. I cannot set a specific lower percentage. Because I dont know what it would be in pixels. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the css calc() function as it should help you accomplish this task. For example:

```
.my-element {
    width: calc(50% - 1px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 30px border is adding on to the 50% width of `#div1` to compensate for that extra border, you could add

```
<div style="float:left;width:calc(50% - 30px);background-color:#58c333;" id="div1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? I kept both divs on the same line by adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to #div1, and I also changed the inline css for the first div from `padding: 11px` to `padding: 12px`.

```css
 #div1 {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   display: inline-block;
   border-left: 30px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 30px solid #24890d;
   height: 0;
   line-height: 50px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;background-color: red">
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#58c333;padding-top: 12px">
    aa
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#58c333;" id="div1">
    bb
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

less sharp, you could use a gradient and eventually flexmodel to draw an oblique line and allow it to go through many lines.

```css
.oblique {
  display:flex;
  background:linear-gradient(to left, green 50%,tomato 50%)
}
.oblique:before {
  content:'';
  background:linear-gradient(to top left,  green 49%,tomato 51%);
  display:block;
  width:3em;
  order:1;
}
.oblique .first {
  order:0;
}
.oblique .first + div {
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="oblique">
  <div class="first"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
  <div><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[box-sizing: border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) So the border is included in the width calculation

```css
#div1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #24890d;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Added this */
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;background-color: red">
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#58c333;padding-top: 11px">
    aa
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#58c333;" id="div1">
    bb
  </div>
</div>
```